# How do I backup an svn repository so the revision logs are still visible after the svn server is gone?

Tags: svn

There are some old projects I have at a remote svn server. I can connect to the repositories with my svn client and examine the logs. I can also export the repository so the source are all local to my drive on my Mac.

But an export doesn't appear to include the logs They are just a complete backup of the source.

However, if I checkout the repository, even though I can see the logs I understand that if the remote svn server is no longer available the revision logs will no longer be visible.

So my question is, what's the best way to (1) backup a repository locally on my own computer and (2) still be able to see the revision logs later on, after the svn from which I checked out is gone?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `export` *isn't* a "complete backup of the source" - it is a copy of the repository state at a given point in time, which is disconnected from the repository.

If you want to see the revision history/logs, you need a copy of the repository itself, in a format that can be read/processed by the Subversion server libraries.

This means either dumping the repository and loading it into a local one, or mirroring the repository elsewhere.

You can dump the remote repository with [`svnrdump`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnrdump.c.dump.html), then `svnadmin create` a local repository and `svnadmin load` the dumpfile into it.

If you have SSH or similar access to the remote server and it can reach your Mac via the network, you can [`svnsync`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk.svnsync) the repository to a repository on your local machine, which may or may not be faster.

For full details, the [Subversion Manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate) comes through as usual.

Comment: Thanks. In addition to your guidance, I found this page very helpful in preparing the dump-to-local repository steps: https://shravanmahankali.wordpress.com/tag/subversion-from-windows-to-mac-os-x/

In particular, the "svnadmin create /svnrepo" was vital to create the svn repository folder structure before running "svnadmin load".

It's working now. Thanks.